# Feed SELECT with JSON values and set selected value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, select

I'm trying to feed a SELECT element using JSON values but I can not get it to work. I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9EqzL2LbS5wymOb1tUT9) to try out but really don't know where my mistake is. I read also [AngularJS API for select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), any help on this?

Comment: `$scope.name` doesnt contain an array, `$scope.name.status` however...

Comment: @tymeJV not work, I updated the plunker and results are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never declare your app in the HTML, you have `angular.module("plunker", [])` -- so you need `ng-app="plunker"` in your HTML.

Add `ng-app="plunker"` to your `body` tag

Comment: Yes, that is what I miss but default value doesn't work, why?

Comment: @ReynierPM -- Set the select `ng-model` variable to the array index you want: `$scope.updStatus = $scope.options.status[1];`

Comment: I did and default option is not selected see here http://plnkr.co/edit/9EqzL2LbS5wymOb1tUT9, I tried also using `ng-init` but doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

You havn't added `ng-app` in your code. Add it and try again.